# Actionscript 3 - Stack overflow on gotoAndStop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I'm porting a game from Actionscript 2 to Actionscript 3, and this funky error is keeping me from further debugging.

It's a stack overflow error (gotta love stack overflow!), that apparently occurs on a gotoAndStop function, which is native AS3 code.

Unfortunately I have no idea where the context of this behavior is happening at. It seems like stack overflow error crashes the debugger, so the long error message below is all I have to work with. It seems extremely internal, yet it persists.

Has anyone experienced, or can give tips/insight on this (or a similar) error in AS3?

```
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at block/frame1()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at block/frame1()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at block/frame1()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at block/frame1()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at block/frame1()
```

Here is the line where this error occurs:

```
childClip.gotoAndStop(MovieClip(root).someVariable[value]);
```

Comment: First thing is to go into your publish settings and check 'Permit debugging' which will show you the line numbers where the error is happening.

Comment: Yes, make sure you are actually debugging.  Show whatever block of code your using that calls the `gotoAndStop`

Comment: @Scott That's actually a fantastic tip! Thanks!
The line of code is basically `childClip.gotoAndStop(MovieClip(root).someVariable[value]);`.
The child clip is a different type of MovieClip.

Comment: Without seeing any code I would guess that the gotoAndStop is calling another gotoAndStop to run which calls the 1st one again and so forth.

Comment: @Scott That's what came to my mind first too, but it seems highly incorrect in context...
Is there a behavioral change between AS2 and AS3 that would make this issue (does gotoAndStop now instantly run the code on the target frame?)? Also, the gotoAndStop call that the error is on, is located at the first frame of the main timeline of the parent MovieClip, so it can't be rerun through a routine (it's not in a function).
Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure of the behavioral changes between the two but I do know that if you take AS2 code and try to run it as AS3 you can get funky error messages that obfuscate the actual problem.

Comment: @Scott I've had a lot of those errors at the start. Well I guess this is as far as we'll get to solving the issue for now. Thanks for the talk; it helped! :D

Comment: use type casting as3 is strict language MovieClip(your clip).gotoAndStop(2); sprite(yousprite).gotoAndStop(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

I did a bunch of debugging. I must thank @LDMS for noting the simple non-debug-mode debug feature of AS3 that helped a ton!

There was a series of behaviors that caused this issue.

1. The first issue that caused the stack overflow was the fact that gotoAndStop() immediately executes the code on the target frame.
2. The currently executing code on the target movie clip will be interrupted when gotoAndStop() occurs. This is why the error was difficult to track - it happened seemingly at random (yet every time, because of the number of executions upon loading the program).
3. The first frame included function variables (such as `var someFunction:Function;`).

It appears that the gotoAndStop() function was halting the function variables from initializing on the first frame, immediately. Then it would attempt to go to some frame, which might have used one of the functions, causing the error checking to behave oddly, then detecting a stack overflow.

The solution was to have the target instance call the original gotoAndStop() function at the end of the first frame's line of code. That way, the gotoAndStop() function will not happen during the execution of code. It's synchronous.

Hopefully this helps someone else with a similar issue in the future!

Answer (score 0):

should check if there is any code written on the actual frame where you send the playhead in the first place
you are getting into an infinite loop, the playhead runs in circles.
you should set a breakpoint early in the app, and step-in (f5) all the way.

Comment: So I placed a breakpoint on the gotoAndStop line. I played the code a few hundred times until the got to the stack.
This time it gave me a very large debugging message.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3tmn3vEf

Can I get any useful information from this?

Comment: holy camoly! Is it possible that you have more than 3891 lines of code on the 8th frame of the main timeline? Writing code on frames is a nightmare to debug... can you send us some actual code? my guess is that its not a single bug.

Comment: Haha, yep, I have 8832 lines of code on the 8th frame. Yes you're right, debugging code with MovieClips is definitely a nightmare. That's why I've moved to BitmapData now. However for this project I can't simply use bitmaps; it's too complex! What code are you interested in seeing? I'm not exactly sure what would be relevant. The gotoAndStop snippet is on the main code (first frame, not in a block) of the tile MovieClip. It tells the tile's image to go to its corresponding frame.

Comment: maan :D sorry to say, but you are doomed! So if its a tile MovieClip, you must have quite a few of them on the stage, it entirely possible that you have hit some as3 limitation and the code doesn't even run properly. The timeline shouldn't be used to store different states of an object that way. My best advise would be to try to move the code into a proper editor (flashdevelop for example), detach it from the frames. Instantiate clips from library, jump to their proper (code free)frame. Your chances of finding any bug will be much much higher! Its a pain, but a manageable one :)

Comment: Well having a few hundred types of tiles (most of them have specific behaviors/animations), it's not really feasible, haha. I just can't imagine why there is a stack overflow with this simple line of code.